# solrnet spellcheck.collation implementation does not support multiple collation

Tags: solr, spell-checking, solrnet

I am using solrnet and I want to use the spellcheck collation feature of solr. But it appears that solrnet does not support multiple collation. Is there a workaround for this ?

```
var queryResult = solr.Query(finalQuery, queryOptions);
```

`queryResult.SpellChecking.Collation` // this property is a string instead of a collection

---

**Detailed explanation**

I set in solr `<str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>` and this returns me more than one collation for one query

For this query:    `/select/?spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=draiving+AND+tess` i get two collation

```
<str name="collation">driving AND test</str>
<str name="collation">training AND test</str>
```

In solrnet I have access only to first collation.

I think this is a bug in solrnet and I am opened to fix this if you also think this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [outstanding pull request](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/pull/24) on the SolrNet Github project that addresses this issue. Unfortunately, the committer of that pull request has not responded to some questions by the SolrNet author - Mauricio Scheffer. Since you are open to fixing this issue as well, I would suggest posting over st the [SolrNet Google Groups Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/solrnet) and open a discussion with Mauricio about perhaps finishing off the changes or starting your own. Unfortunately, Mauricio does not respond to questions/posts here on StackOverflow anymore, due to past censorship issues.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your suggestions. I will try to contribute to the project and fix this bug.